# How can I parse this JSON-like structure with multiple identical keys but different values?

Tags: javascript, json

I have Json Structured data which is coming from backend, when i try to Parse it using Javascript JSON.parse, it's creating problem for me. i have multiple node with same key, and when parsed it gives only one node. below is the JSON Structure. i have also created jsfiddle for the same : http://jsfiddle.net/DYZR4/, you can copy the structure and check it in "http://json.parser.online.fr/", just see how JS veal is constructed.

```
{
   "metadata":{
      "USER_TYPE":"APPLE LEAD"
   },
   "TODAY":[
      {
         "REPORT_TYPE":"TODAY",
         "VISIT_STATUS":"Audit In Progress",
         "VISIT_STATUS_ID":"4",
         "VISIT_ID":"V100-5293-2013-11",
         "USER_ID":"100124",
         "APP_ASSIGNMENT_ID":"3",
         "METRIC_ID":"101652",
         "PID":"139876",
         "INSTANCE_ID":"",
         "IS_OFFLINE":"",
         "FACILITY_ID":"5293",
         "FACILITY_NAME":"ABC",
         "CITY":"Singapore",
         "STATE_PROVINCE":"Singapore",
         "COUNTRY":"Singapore",
         "FACILITY_ADDRESS":"ABCSDASDSDSADD",
         "FACILITY_LOCAL_NAME":"",
         "FACILITY_LOCAL_ADDRESS":"",
         "LONGITUDE":"",
         "LATITUDE":"",
         "VISIT_EDIT_FLAG":"D",
         "VS_EDIT_FLAG":"D",
         "VS_PID":"139870",
         "VS_METRIC_ID":"101661",
         "ONSITE_LEAD":"Eve SGM",
         "APPLE_LEAD":"Lara SGM",
         "APPLE_VERIFICATION_LEAD":"Nina SGM",
         "SR_PROGRAM_MANAGER":"Bob SGM",
         "START_DATE":"14-NOV-13",
         "PROTOCOL_NAME":"Code of Conduct Provision - November Protocol",
         "TPA_DATE":"NOV 22,2013",
         "FINAL_REPORT_DEADLINE":"NOV 26,2013",
         "SHOW_DATE":"NOV 14 - NOV 15,2013",
         "AUDIT_COMPANIES":[
            {
               "AUDIT_COMPANY":"Golder",
               "AUDITORS":[
                  {
                     "TPA_AUDITOR":"Jake",
                     "IS_LEAD":"1",
                     "ASSIGNMENTS":[
                        {
                           "ASSIGNMENTS":"Facility"
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "TPA_AUDITOR":"Jasmi",
                     "IS_LEAD":"0",
                     "ASSIGNMENTS":[
                        {
                           "ASSIGNMENTS":"Facility"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "TODAY":[
      {
         "REPORT_TYPE":"TODAY",
         "VISIT_STATUS":"Audit In Progress",
         "VISIT_STATUS_ID":"4",
         "VISIT_ID":"V98-5293-2013-11",
         "USER_ID":"100124",
         "APP_ASSIGNMENT_ID":"3",
         "METRIC_ID":"101652",
         "PID":"139018",
         "INSTANCE_ID":"",
         "IS_OFFLINE":"",
         "FACILITY_ID":"5293",
         "FACILITY_NAME":"XYZ",
         "CITY":"Singapore",
         "STATE_PROVINCE":"Singapore",
         "COUNTRY":"Singapore",
         "FACILITY_ADDRESS":"",
         "FACILITY_LOCAL_NAME":"",
         "FACILITY_LOCAL_ADDRESS":"",
         "LONGITUDE":"",
         "LATITUDE":"",
         "VISIT_EDIT_FLAG":"D",
         "VS_EDIT_FLAG":"Y",
         "VS_PID":"139014",
         "VS_METRIC_ID":"101661",
         "ONSITE_LEAD":"Eve",
         "APPLE_LEAD":"Eve",
         "APPLE_VERIFICATION_LEAD":"Nin",
         "SR_PROGRAM_MANAGER":"Fanky",
         "START_DATE":"14-NOV-13",
         "PROTOCOL_NAME":"Protocol test by sreedhar to validate CAP",
         "TPA_DATE":"NOV 22,2013",
         "FINAL_REPORT_DEADLINE":"NOV 26,2013",
         "SHOW_DATE":"NOV 14 - NOV 15,2013",
         "AUDIT_COMPANIES":[
            {
               "AUDIT_COMPANY":"Verite",
               "AUDITORS":[
                  {
                     "TPA_AUDITOR":"Scott SGM",
                     "IS_LEAD":"0",
                     "ASSIGNMENTS":[
                        {
                           "ASSIGNMENTS":"Property Protection"
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "TPA_AUDITOR":"Charles SGM",
                     "IS_LEAD":"1",
                     "ASSIGNMENTS":[
                        {
                           "ASSIGNMENTS":"Ethics"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "TODAY":[
      {
         "REPORT_TYPE":"TODAY",
         "VISIT_STATUS":"Audit In Progress",
         "VISIT_STATUS_ID":"4",
         "VISIT_ID":"V11-5300-2013-11",
         "USER_ID":"100124",
         "APP_ASSIGNMENT_ID":"3",
         "METRIC_ID":"101652",
         "PID":"139047",
         "INSTANCE_ID":"",
         "IS_OFFLINE":"",
         "FACILITY_ID":"5300",
         "FACILITY_NAME":"CDE",
         "CITY":"Downers Grove",
         "STATE_PROVINCE":"Illinois",
         "COUNTRY":"USA",
         "FACILITY_ADDRESS":"5200 Road",
         "FACILITY_LOCAL_NAME":"",
         "FACILITY_LOCAL_ADDRESS":"",
         "LONGITUDE":"",
         "LATITUDE":"",
         "VISIT_EDIT_FLAG":"D",
         "VS_EDIT_FLAG":"Y",
         "VS_PID":"139040",
         "VS_METRIC_ID":"101661",
         "ONSITE_LEAD":"Eve",
         "APPLE_LEAD":"Eve",
         "APPLE_VERIFICATION_LEAD":"Nina",
         "SR_PROGRAM_MANAGER":"Fanky",
         "START_DATE":"14-NOV-13",
         "PROTOCOL_NAME":"Code of Conduct Provision - November Protocol",
         "TPA_DATE":"NOV 22,2013",
         "FINAL_REPORT_DEADLINE":"NOV 26,2013",
         "SHOW_DATE":"NOV 14 - NOV 15,2013",
         "AUDIT_COMPANIES":[
            {
               "AUDIT_COMPANY":"Golder",
               "AUDITORS":[
                  {
                     "TPA_AUDITOR":"Jake SGM",
                     "IS_LEAD":"1",
                     "ASSIGNMENTS":[
                        {
                           "ASSIGNMENTS":"Emergency Prevention, Preparedness and Response"
                        },
                        {
                           "ASSIGNMENTS":"Ethics"
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "TPA_AUDITOR":"Jasmin SGM",
                     "IS_LEAD":"0",
                     "ASSIGNMENTS":[
                        {
                           "ASSIGNMENTS":"Labor &#38; Human Rights"
                        },
                        {
                           "ASSIGNMENTS":"Management Systems"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "AUDIT_COMPANY":"Verite",
               "AUDITORS":[
                  {
                     "TPA_AUDITOR":"Charles SGM",
                     "IS_LEAD":"1",
                     "ASSIGNMENTS":[
                        {
                           "ASSIGNMENTS":"Emergency Prevention, Preparedness and Response"
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "TPA_AUDITOR":"David SGM",
                     "IS_LEAD":"0",
                     "ASSIGNMENTS":[
                        {
                           "ASSIGNMENTS":"Hazardous Substance Management and Restrictions"
                        },
                        {
                           "ASSIGNMENTS":"Hazardous Substance Management and Restrictions 1"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "TODAY":[
      {
         "REPORT_TYPE":"TODAY",
         "VISIT_STATUS":"Audit In Progress",
         "VISIT_STATUS_ID":"4",
         "VISIT_ID":"V13-4002-2013-11",
         "USER_ID":"100124",
         "APP_ASSIGNMENT_ID":"3",
         "METRIC_ID":"101652",
         "PID":"145748",
         "INSTANCE_ID":"",
         "IS_OFFLINE":"N",
         "FACILITY_ID":"4002",
         "FACILITY_NAME":"AAC",
         "CITY":"Shenzhen",
         "STATE_PROVINCE":"Guangdong",
         "COUNTRY":"China",
         "FACILITY_ADDRESS":"Dsdiang District",
         "FACILITY_LOCAL_NAME":"",
         "FACILITY_LOCAL_ADDRESS":"",
         "LONGITUDE":"",
         "LATITUDE":"",
         "VISIT_EDIT_FLAG":"D",
         "VS_EDIT_FLAG":"D",
         "VS_PID":"145691",
         "VS_METRIC_ID":"101661",
         "ONSITE_LEAD":"Eve SGM",
         "APPLE_LEAD":"Lara SGM",
         "APPLE_VERIFICATION_LEAD":"Nina SGM",
         "SR_PROGRAM_MANAGER":"Bob SGM",
         "START_DATE":"18-NOV-13",
         "PROTOCOL_NAME":"Test Protocol 10",
         "TPA_DATE":"DEC 06,2013",
         "FINAL_REPORT_DEADLINE":"DEC 10,2013",
         "SHOW_DATE":"NOV 18 - NOV 30,2013",
         "AUDIT_COMPANIES":[
            {
               "AUDIT_COMPANY":"Golder",
               "AUDITORS":[
                  {
                     "TPA_AUDITOR":"Jake SGM",
                     "IS_LEAD":"0",
                     "ASSIGNMENTS":[
                        {
                           "ASSIGNMENTS":"Labor &#38; Human Rights"
                        },
                        {
                           "ASSIGNMENTS":"Wages &#38; Benefits"
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "TPA_AUDITOR":"Jasmin SGM",
                     "IS_LEAD":"0",
                     "ASSIGNMENTS":[
                        {
                           "ASSIGNMENTS":"Antidiscrimination"
                        },
                        {
                           "ASSIGNMENTS":"Labor &#38; Human Rights"
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "TPA_AUDITOR":"Yasmin SGM",
                     "IS_LEAD":"1",
                     "ASSIGNMENTS":[
                        {
                           "ASSIGNMENTS":"Antidiscrimination"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "AUDIT_COMPANY":"PWC",
               "AUDITORS":[
                  {
                     "TPA_AUDITOR":"Leo SGM",
                     "IS_LEAD":"1",
                     "ASSIGNMENTS":[
                        {
                           "ASSIGNMENTS":"Antidiscrimination"
                        },
                        {
                           "ASSIGNMENTS":"Labor &#38; Human Rights"
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "TPA_AUDITOR":"Maggie SGM",
                     "IS_LEAD":"0",
                     "ASSIGNMENTS":[
                        {
                           "ASSIGNMENTS":"Labor &#38; Human Rights"
                        },
                        {
                           "ASSIGNMENTS":"Wages &#38; Benefits"
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "TPA_AUDITOR":"Maria SGM",
                     "IS_LEAD":"0",
                     "ASSIGNMENTS":[
                        {
                           "ASSIGNMENTS":"Antidiscrimination"
                        },
                        {
                           "ASSIGNMENTS":"Labor &#38; Human Rights"
                        },
                        {
                           "ASSIGNMENTS":"Wages &#38; Benefits"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "AUDIT_COMPANY":"Supplier Responsibility",
               "AUDITORS":[
                  {
                     "TPA_AUDITOR":"Gia SGM",
                     "IS_LEAD":"1",
                     "ASSIGNMENTS":[
                        {
                           "ASSIGNMENTS":"Antidiscrimination"
                        },
                        {
                           "ASSIGNMENTS":"Labor &#38; Human Rights"
                        },
                        {
                           "ASSIGNMENTS":"Wages &#38; Benefits"
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "TPA_AUDITOR":"Ruth SGM",
                     "IS_LEAD":"0",
                     "ASSIGNMENTS":[
                        {
                           "ASSIGNMENTS":"Antidiscrimination"
                        },
                        {
                           "ASSIGNMENTS":"Labor &#38; Human Rights"
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "TPA_AUDITOR":"Ryan SGM",
                     "IS_LEAD":"0",
                     "ASSIGNMENTS":[
                        {
                           "ASSIGNMENTS":"Labor &#38; Human Rights"
                        },
                        {
                           "ASSIGNMENTS":"Wages &#38; Benefits"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "AUDIT_COMPANY":"Verite",
               "AUDITORS":[
                  {
                     "TPA_AUDITOR":"Charles SGM",
                     "IS_LEAD":"1",
                     "ASSIGNMENTS":[
                        {
                           "ASSIGNMENTS":"Antidiscrimination"
                        },
                        {
                           "ASSIGNMENTS":"Labor &#38; Human Rights"
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "TPA_AUDITOR":"David SGM",
                     "IS_LEAD":"0",
                     "ASSIGNMENTS":[
                        {
                           "ASSIGNMENTS":"Antidiscrimination"
                        },
                        {
                           "ASSIGNMENTS":"Labor &#38; Human Rights"
                        },
                        {
                           "ASSIGNMENTS":"Wages &#38; Benefits"
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "TPA_AUDITOR":"Scott SGM",
                     "IS_LEAD":"0",
                     "ASSIGNMENTS":[
                        {
                           "ASSIGNMENTS":"Labor &#38; Human Rights"
                        },
                        {
                           "ASSIGNMENTS":"Wages &#38; Benefits"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "TODAY":[
      {
         "REPORT_TYPE":"TODAY",
         "VISIT_STATUS":"Audit In Progress",
         "VISIT_STATUS_ID":"4",
         "VISIT_ID":"V15-5343-2013-11",
         "USER_ID":"100124",
         "APP_ASSIGNMENT_ID":"3",
         "METRIC_ID":"101652",
         "PID":"138985",
         "INSTANCE_ID":"",
         "IS_OFFLINE":"",
         "FACILITY_ID":"5343",
         "FACILITY_NAME":"Cable",
         "CITY":"Shenzhen",
         "STATE_PROVINCE":"Guangdong",
         "COUNTRY":"China",
         "FACILITY_ADDRESS":"No. 1173 Henggang",
         "FACILITY_LOCAL_NAME":"",
         "FACILITY_LOCAL_ADDRESS":"",
         "LONGITUDE":"",
         "LATITUDE":"",
         "VISIT_EDIT_FLAG":"D",
         "VS_EDIT_FLAG":"D",
         "VS_PID":"138969",
         "VS_METRIC_ID":"101661",
         "ONSITE_LEAD":"Eve SGM",
         "APPLE_LEAD":"S48 Rao",
         "APPLE_VERIFICATION_LEAD":"Nina SGM",
         "SR_PROGRAM_MANAGER":"Fanky SGM",
         "START_DATE":"14-NOV-13",
         "PROTOCOL_NAME":"Protocol by sreedhar test",
         "TPA_DATE":"NOV 14,2013",
         "FINAL_REPORT_DEADLINE":"NOV 15,2013",
         "SHOW_DATE":"NOV 14 - NOV 14,2013",
         "AUDIT_COMPANIES":[
            {
               "AUDIT_COMPANY":"PWC",
               "AUDITORS":[
                  {
                     "TPA_AUDITOR":"Leo SGM",
                     "IS_LEAD":"1",
                     "ASSIGNMENTS":[
                        {
                           "ASSIGNMENTS":"Facility"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "TODAY":[
      {
         "REPORT_TYPE":"TODAY",
         "VISIT_STATUS":"Audit In Progress",
         "VISIT_STATUS_ID":"4",
         "VISIT_ID":"V8-5342-2013-11",
         "USER_ID":"100124",
         "APP_ASSIGNMENT_ID":"3",
         "METRIC_ID":"101652",
         "PID":"140688",
         "INSTANCE_ID":"",
         "IS_OFFLINE":"N",
         "FACILITY_ID":"5342",
         "FACILITY_NAME":"Vitalo Packaging Co. Ltd.",
         "CITY":"Suzhou",
         "STATE_PROVINCE":"Jiangsu",
         "COUNTRY":"China",
         "FACILITY_ADDRESS":"Suzhou",
         "FACILITY_LOCAL_NAME":"",
         "FACILITY_LOCAL_ADDRESS":"",
         "LONGITUDE":"",
         "LATITUDE":"",
         "VISIT_EDIT_FLAG":"D",
         "VS_EDIT_FLAG":"D",
         "VS_PID":"140684",
         "VS_METRIC_ID":"101661",
         "ONSITE_LEAD":"Eve SGM",
         "APPLE_LEAD":"Lara SGM",
         "APPLE_VERIFICATION_LEAD":"Nina SGM",
         "SR_PROGRAM_MANAGER":"Tom SGM",
         "START_DATE":"15-NOV-13",
         "PROTOCOL_NAME":"Code of Conduct Provision - November Protocol",
         "TPA_DATE":"NOV 22,2013",
         "FINAL_REPORT_DEADLINE":"NOV 26,2013",
         "SHOW_DATE":"NOV 15 - NOV 16,2013",
         "AUDIT_COMPANIES":[
            {
               "AUDIT_COMPANY":"Golder",
               "AUDITORS":[
                  {
                     "TPA_AUDITOR":"Yasmin SGM",
                     "IS_LEAD":"0",
                     "ASSIGNMENTS":[
                        {
                           "ASSIGNMENTS":"Facility"
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "TPA_AUDITOR":"Jasmin SGM",
                     "IS_LEAD":"1",
                     "ASSIGNMENTS":[
                        {
                           "ASSIGNMENTS":""
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "UPCOMING":[
      {
         "REPORT_TYPE":"UPCOMING",
         "VISIT_STATUS":"Pre-Audit - Audit Planned",
         "VISIT_STATUS_ID":"1",
         "VISIT_ID":"V5-5349-2013-11",
         "USER_ID":"100124",
         "APP_ASSIGNMENT_ID":"3",
         "METRIC_ID":"101652",
         "PID":"145848",
         "INSTANCE_ID":"",
         "IS_OFFLINE":"N",
         "FACILITY_ID":"5349",
         "FACILITY_NAME":"Advanced Inc.",
         "CITY":"Kaohsiung",
         "STATE_PROVINCE":"Kaohsiung",
         "COUNTRY":"Taiwan",
         "FACILITY_ADDRESS":"No.18 North6",
         "FACILITY_LOCAL_NAME":"",
         "FACILITY_LOCAL_ADDRESS":"",
         "LONGITUDE":"",
         "LATITUDE":"",
         "VISIT_EDIT_FLAG":"D",
         "VS_EDIT_FLAG":"Y",
         "VS_PID":"145840",
         "VS_METRIC_ID":"101661",
         "ONSITE_LEAD":"Eve SGM",
         "APPLE_LEAD":"Eve SGM",
         "APPLE_VERIFICATION_LEAD":"Nina SGM",
         "SR_PROGRAM_MANAGER":"Bob SGM",
         "START_DATE":"20-NOV-13",
         "PROTOCOL_NAME":"Test Protocol 10",
         "TPA_DATE":"NOV 29,2013",
         "FINAL_REPORT_DEADLINE":"DEC 03,2013",
         "SHOW_DATE":"NOV 20 - NOV 22,2013",
         "AUDIT_COMPANIES":[
            {
               "AUDIT_COMPANY":"Golder",
               "AUDITORS":[
                  {
                     "TPA_AUDITOR":"Jasmin SGM",
                     "IS_LEAD":"1",
                     "ASSIGNMENTS":[
                        {
                           "ASSIGNMENTS":"Labor &#38; Human Rights"
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "TPA_AUDITOR":"Jake SGM",
                     "IS_LEAD":"0",
                     "ASSIGNMENTS":[
                        {
                           "ASSIGNMENTS":"Wages &#38; Benefits"
                        },
                        {
                           "ASSIGNMENTS":"Antidiscrimination"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "UPCOMING":[
      {
         "REPORT_TYPE":"UPCOMING",
         "VISIT_STATUS":"Pre-Audit - Audit Planned",
         "VISIT_STATUS_ID":"1",
         "VISIT_ID":"V280-5287-2013-11",
         "USER_ID":"100124",
         "APP_ASSIGNMENT_ID":"3",
         "METRIC_ID":"101652",
         "PID":"139688",
         "INSTANCE_ID":"",
         "IS_OFFLINE":"",
         "FACILITY_ID":"5287",
         "FACILITY_NAME":"Uniparts",
         "CITY":"Lutterworth",
         "STATE_PROVINCE":"Lutterworth",
         "COUNTRY":"United Kingdom",
         "FACILITY_ADDRESS":"Magna Park",
         "FACILITY_LOCAL_NAME":"",
         "FACILITY_LOCAL_ADDRESS":"",
         "LONGITUDE":"",
         "LATITUDE":"",
         "VISIT_EDIT_FLAG":"D",
         "VS_EDIT_FLAG":"D",
         "VS_PID":"139683",
         "VS_METRIC_ID":"101661",
         "ONSITE_LEAD":"Eve SGM",
         "APPLE_LEAD":"Lara SGM",
         "APPLE_VERIFICATION_LEAD":"Nina SGM",
         "SR_PROGRAM_MANAGER":"Fanky SGM",
         "START_DATE":"15-NOV-13",
         "PROTOCOL_NAME":"Test Protocol 10",
         "TPA_DATE":"NOV 22,2013",
         "FINAL_REPORT_DEADLINE":"NOV 26,2013",
         "SHOW_DATE":"NOV 15 - NOV 15,2013",
         "AUDIT_COMPANIES":[
            {
               "AUDIT_COMPANY":"Golder",
               "AUDITORS":[
                  {
                     "TPA_AUDITOR":"Jasmin SGM",
                     "IS_LEAD":"0",
                     "ASSIGNMENTS":[
                        {
                           "ASSIGNMENTS":"Antidiscrimination"
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "TPA_AUDITOR":"Jake SGM",
                     "IS_LEAD":"1",
                     "ASSIGNMENTS":[
                        {
                           "ASSIGNMENTS":""
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can have, on the same level, two properties with the same name because one will override the other one while parsing from JSON to an actual JS object

Comment: @BeNdErR is there any way i can prevent it to override ?

Comment: you should change the property name or, as suggested by Drax, change it into an array.

Comment: how can i change the property name ? or turn into an array ? any sample. ?

Comment: is there any way i can remove the Key itself for e.g. : "TODAY".

Comment: You can't remove the key easily, without parsing the JSON first, but you can modify it to a different value relatively easily using RegExp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### a slight hack..

If you know what each of the duplicated keys are, and they are unique from other keys used within the sub-data structures, you could use a regular expression to modify them before parsing.

*The regular expression below relies on the fact that your keys will be formed with no whitespace between the closing quote (`"`) and the full colon (`:`) — for simplicity. If this isn't the case though, it could be upgraded to handle whatever situations are causing the problem.*

```
 /// load the JSON string into data, shortened example used below
var data = '{ "TODAY": [], "TODAY": [], "UPCOMING": [] }',
    keys = ['TODAY', 'UPCOMING'], /// set your keys here
    rexp = new RegExp('"(' + keys.join('|') + ')(?=":)', 'g'),
    seen = {};

data = data.replace(rexp, function(match){
  if ( seen[match] ) {
    return match + '_' + (seen[match]++);
  }
  else {
    seen[match] = 1;
    return match;
  }
});

console.log(data);
/// { "TODAY": [], "TODAY_1": [], "UPCOMING": []}
```

The above would then at least allow you to get at all the data from the client side, you could then step each item and strip off the added `_1`, `_2` and so on, and then save elsewhere to your own array.

If these keys do occur lower down in your dataset, you will find they have been replaced as well, but this would be an easy thing to detect and repair as you use the data.

Comment: @user2798628 ~ no worries :) it's always a trick trying to fix bad server-side output on the client-side... but sometimes you have no choice; Don't forget to accept the answer if it was of use.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to have "multiple nodes with same key" on json, that should be an array.
You need some kind of data transformation before parsing it.

Looking at your data, your "TODAY" nodes are all arrays of one element, if you manage to turn that into one array containing all elements it should solve your problem.

Comment: Is there any way i can do it ? cos backend code i am not able to change as of now. whatever it is i have to do at the front end.

Comment: how can i turn it into one array, really sorry fa bugging but i don't have much knowledge on javascript.

Comment: You need to modify the string manually so it fits your needs, whatever they are. Or you might be able to find a library that automatically parses json and collapses multiple keys as an array.